# Azure Custom Logging

Tags: c#, azure, logging

I've been looking into logging for my Web Api application hosted within Azure.

The information I've discovered essentially shows how tp write the logs into Azure Storage.

Is there a way to write/store logs as a file instead, similar to a text file?

When I go to the dashboard of my Azure Web App, I can access FTP Diagnostics logs which are in the format I want.  Is there a way to create and write to such files?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea, since you don't have control over the virtual machine that is running your app. So you can't write to path, because they(Microsoft) can move your application to another virtual machine and your log won't exist in the new VM.

The best you can do is keep with log on Storage Account using Table Service.